VS Code devcontainer some extensions not installed
I started using Devcontainer in VS Code, I use a UBI9 base image. I wanted to have my extensions in the Devcontainer so I listed them in devcontainer.json. As host system I use Rocky Linux 9 and Windows, my issue happens on both.
For some reason when opening the container, not all listed extensions are installed, just about half of them.
For example CMake is not installed:

Even though it´s listed:
"customizations": {
        // Configure properties specific to VS Code.
        "vscode": {
            // Add the IDs of extensions you want installed when the container is created.
            "extensions": [
                "donjayamanne.githistory",
                "jeff-hykin.better-cpp-syntax",
                "mhutchie.git-graph",
                "ms-vscode.cmake-tools",
                "ms-vscode.cpptools",
                "ms-vscode.cpptools-extension-pack",
                "ms-vscode.cpptools-themes",
                "ms-vsliveshare.vsliveshare",
                "njpwerner.autodocstring",
                "shardulm94.trailing-spaces",
                "SonarSource.sonarlint-vscode",
                "TabNine.tabnine-vscode",
                "twxs.cmake",
                "VisualStudioExptTeam.intellicode-api-usage-examples",
                "VisualStudioExptTeam.vscodeintellicode"
            ]
        }
    }

I found this issue on github: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/8097 but it says this issue has been fixed.
I get this log:
2024-06-22 18:07:12.162 [info] Getting Manifest... twxs.cmake
2024-06-22 18:07:12.350 [info] Skipping the packed extension as it cannot be installed twxs.cmake self-signed certificate in certificate chain
...
2024-06-22 18:07:17.294 [error] Error: Failed Installing Extensions: jeff-hykin.better-cpp-syntax, donjayamanne.githistory, mhutchie.git-graph, njpwerner.autodocstring, ms-vsliveshare.vsliveshare, sonarsource.sonarlint-vscode, shardulm94.trailing-spaces, twxs.cmake, tabnine.tabnine-vscode, visualstudioexptteam.vscodeintellicode, visualstudioexptteam.intellicode-api-usage-examples
    at a.installExtensions (/vscode/vscode-server/bin/linux-x64/611f9bfce64f25108829dd295f54a6894e87339d/out/vs/server/node/server.main.js:145:9966)

It says self-signed certificate in certificate chain as I am using the VPN of my company. Unfortunately it is not possible to deactivate the VPN.
However if I press Install in Dev Container, then the extension is installed without any issues. Giving this log:
2024-06-22 18:09:28.062 [info] Getting Manifest... twxs.cmake
2024-06-22 18:09:30.452 [info] Downloaded extension to file:///home/vscode/.vscode-server/extensionsCache/57cfd2e8-928e-4d1a-b422-a0e4e146c9fb
2024-06-22 18:09:30.457 [info] Installing extension: twxs.cmake file:///home/vscode/.vscode-server/extensions/extensions.json
2024-06-22 18:09:30.457 [info] Installing the extension without checking dependencies and pack twxs.cmake
2024-06-22 18:09:30.666 [info] Extracted extension to file:///home/vscode/.vscode-server/extensions/twxs.cmake-0.0.17: twxs.cmake
2024-06-22 18:09:30.677 [info] Renamed to /home/vscode/.vscode-server/extensions/twxs.cmake-0.0.17
2024-06-22 18:09:30.742 [info] Extension installed successfully: twxs.cmake file:///home/vscode/.vscode-server/extensions/extensions.json

Update: I found a way to deactivate the VPN and turned out that without VPN it successfully installs all extensions. But this is not a solution to the problem. I have no idea why I can manually install it inside the devcontainer but not via listing it in devcontainer.json

Please post the code and error as text, not a screenshot.

@toyotaSupra Done, thanks for the hint
